# fl.controls.Slider hand cursor won't work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components, cursor, slider

I'm using the fl.controls.Slider class and I can't get it to show a hand cursor when hovering over it. Here's my code.

```
import fl.controls.Slider;

var slider : Slider = new Slider();
slider.x = 100;
slider.y = 100;
slider.width = 168;
slider.mouseEnabled = true;
slider.useHandCursor = true;
slider.buttonMode = true;
slider.mouseChildren = true;
addChild( slider );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fl.controls don't show a hand cursor when enabled. Silly I know. I did find a way to get it to work though. Pass your Slider instance into this function:

```
function addButtonMode(display:*):void
{
    if (display is Sprite)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0;i < display.numChildren;i++)
        {
            addButtonMode(display.getChildAt(i));
        }
        display.useHandCursor = true;
        display.buttonMode = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! This works perfect. My answer is the solution I used that uses the ideas from yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
BaseButton( slider.getChildAt( 0 ) ).useHandCursor = true;
BaseButton( slider.getChildAt( 0 ) ).buttonMode = true;
BaseButton( slider.getChildAt( 1 ) ).useHandCursor = true;
BaseButton( slider.getChildAt( 1 ) ).buttonMode = true;
```

This is the code I ended up using.